# Start LocationListener and SensorEventListener from Android Service

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

I am designing a small android application where I want to register two listeners one is for location change and another is for sensor event from onStartCommand of my service.

I want both the listeners to work simultaneously for which I have started the listeners in two separate handlers but to my surprise only one of the listener is working.

I am new to android, can anyone give me some insight on how to register to separate types of listeners from one android service.

Below is the code snippet.

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

```
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    runnableSpeed = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startLocationListener();
        }
    };
    handlerSpeed.postDelayed(runnableSpeed, 1000);

    runnableGForce = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startAccelerometerListener();
        }
    };
    handlerGForce.postDelayed(runnableGForce, 1000);


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

private void startLocationListener() {

```
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Location: Thread Name" + Thread.currentThread().getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    try {
        gps_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    try {
        network_enabled = locManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    Log.v("Debug", "in on create.. 2");


    if (network_enabled) {
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        Log.v("Debug", "Disabled..");
    }
    if (gps_enabled) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locListener);
        Log.v("Debug", "Enabled..");
    }
    Log.v("Debug", "in on create..3");
}

private void startAccelerometerListener() {
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    accelerometer = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
    sensorManager.registerListener(acceleromterListener, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
```

If I run any one of the listener, both of them works fine separately but when I am running both of them together only sensor events are getting called.

Also when if I print the current thread name it always shows the main thread thought both the listeners are registered in separately.

Comment: _"...only one of the listener is working"_ It would be useful to say which one. Also we don't know what kind of code is in `startLocationListener()` and `startAccelerometerListener()`. (You can edit your question, if you wish.) Anyway, one obvious potential problem is that a location listener will require the location permission. Have you taken care of that?

Comment: Hi, I have given few more details in the post. Yes all the permissions are given and both the listeners separately works fine if I start only one of them. But when both of them does not work simultaneously in service. Can you suggest how to usually start two listeners from the same service.